# Android SMS limit?

Tags: android, sms

Does anybody know what is the limit of sent SMS messages at once? Or it is limited hourly or daily?
I have Nexus 4 (4.4.4 KitKat). I am developing app that sends SMS messages so it is really important to me. I've found a lot of information but it seems none of it is correctly...

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this. If yes, what exactly did you do to so that a device sends many messages. I need to send like 5000 messages in less than 3 hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the creator of this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bamf.smslimittool.donate&hl=en, the limit, since 4.4.1, is 30 messages in 30 minutes.

It also notes that the limit is present to safeguard against malicous programs, so setting it very high is potentially a bad idea.

Comment: well, I understand, thanks! Also, found something here https://plus.google.com/+AlSutton/posts/6XP2HcvPkvX

Comment: And it's not true, by the way. It was before KitKat. Look at SDK. It's down to one minute.

Answer (score 2):

In CM11,

1. Open your Root Explorer.
2. Go in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/
   Open settings.db your SQL editor
3. Open the database ‘Global’
4. Press the Menu button> New Record / New Table
5. As set name: sms_outgoing_check_max_count
6. As value (value) type the maximum number of sms you want, personally I put 2000

Taken from http://www.openeducationus.com/?p=101682

Answer (score 1):

Some limit was introduced not later than Gingerbread. As far as I know, and I investigated thoroughly, it is generally impossible to override these limits on non-rooted devices. If possible, those are rare exceptions. But, if your app is supposed to send messages from your device only or from controlled number of devices, you may get around this problem by setting SMS_OUTGOING_CHECK_MAX_COUNT to a huge number (say 99999) in:

- /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

  1. table *secure*
  2. table *system*
- /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db

  1. table *main*

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it has got anything to do with Android. In India, it is governed by [TRAI Regulations for SMS](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/).

And the limit varies based on whether it is transactional SMS, promotional SMS or personal SMS

*TRAI : Telecom Regulatory Authority of India

Comment: well I think it has to do something with Android because if I send 30 or more messages at once, a confirm popup appears saying "Messaging is sending a large amount of messages.." and you have to confirm every message.