# How to get know of the SMS limits on a not-rooted device?

Tags: android, sms, limit

I read from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24506858/668087) there is a limit on the number of sms an application can send. As stated from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26527040/668087) on the same question, the limits are stored in a database on the device and could be accessed and modified.

I can't find on the Android documentation and with google any official information about these limits and more important how to get them programmatically. So, is there a way for an application to get know of these limits without "root methods"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802289/check-android-package-sms-limit

Comment: Thank you, I will try later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check android package SMS limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802289/check-android-package-sms-limit)